# Write on char array

Tags: android, buffer, inputstream

I want to read from a stream. In entity, i don't set content length and for this, i can't create a buffer with fixed and correct size. I create a buffer with 16384 length but my data is more and a parts of my data lost! I want to read from stream and write to char array and i don't want to read with readLine. How can i write this code? Please explain with a part of code.

Thanks

```
char[] buffer;
        if (contentLength == -1)
            buffer = new char[16038];
        else
            buffer = new char[contentLength];

        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        //String resultS=convertStreamToString(stream);


        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8");
        int hasRead = 0;
        int readSize = 0;
        int bufferLength = buffer.length;

        //List<Byte>  listChar=new ArrayList<Byte>();

        while (hasRead < bufferLength) {
            readSize = streamReader.read(buffer, hasRead, bufferLength
                    - hasRead);
            if (readSize == -1)
                break;
            hasRead += readSize;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code you posted with this:

```
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
char buffer[] = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```

Comment: where i write this code? what i set in append method?

Comment: I write this but end part of my json not return. Why? This is a problem of server or this is problem of client ?

Comment: may be server side problem, you can check if `responseEntity.getContent();` returns proper data or is it `null`